# Inserting a line break in a Access report text field when a certain condition is met

Tags: ms-access, line-breaks

Alright, to begin with, I am not an expert in using reports / forms in Access. The original Access file originates from Access 2000 and I am rebuilding it now to Access 2013, plus adding a few style changes including a line break in a my report.

At first I thought a line break wouldn't be to hard and that I could easily add it in a textbox with either  or & Chr(13) & Chr(10) - also tried it with the $ after the Chr. This didn't worked though.

**The problem / background**

So I have got a report that shows some values that are retrieved from a query. These values are displayed in text boxes.

I have one hidden field that retrieves a single query value (relations) that is inserted in its control source, this seems to work.

The following thing I want to do is checking if the value is not empty, and if it isn't then output the value after a line break.

**More background**

This is being done for address information. Sometimes a relation has 2 address lines instead of just one, so if the relation has 2 lines then it needs to show both lines while if the relation only has one line it should show just one line (without a blank enter). To give an idea:

**Relation A:**

```
Company Name X 
Street Name and number
Zipcode
```

**Relation B:**

```
Company Name Y
Second Name Z 
Street Name and number
Zipcode
```

If I would insert both the company names separate, then you would get a hideous blank line break if the company doesn't have a second name.

**So the textbox code is:**

```
RelationName (retrieved from query)
RelationName2 (retrieved from query)
StreetName (retrieved from query)
Zipcode (retrieved from query)
```

**And for company A it then would look like:**

```
Company Name X 

Street Name and number
Zipcode
```

I thought I could fix this by adding a condition for the second name textbox:

```
=IIf([RelationName2]<>"",Chr(13) & Chr(10) & [RelationName2],"")
```

So if relation name 2 exists, then do a line break and output the second relation name else do nothing (leave empty).

In code this looks like (the {} are textboxes):

```
{RelationName}  {=IIf([RelationName2]<>"",Chr(13) & Chr(10) & [RelationName2],"")}   
{StreetName} 
{Zipcode}
```

The line breaks don't work though, and because of this I also cant test if the line break even works when the condition is met. Perhaps there are other ways to do it (instead of using line breaks). P.S. I also tried setting the textbox text format to rich text instead of plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking for Null and not empty string:

```
IIf(IsNull([RelationName2]), .., ..)
```

Comment: This only partially works. It displays the if and else actions (when i output  simple strings) but so did the <> ""... The line break (still) doesn't seem to work though, also doesn't work when I use the IsNull.

Comment: Can't tell. Chr(13) & Chr(10) is a new line and it works, and the default value of an empty field in Access is Null so that is what to check for. The table can hold zero length strings - "" - but you have configure that explicitly which you probably haven't.

Answer (score 0):

I know this an old post but someone might be helped by this.

I don't know the reason but the following worked for me:

Just switch characters 13 and 10 in your expression. That is:

```
=IIf([RelationName2]<>"",Chr(10) & Chr(13) & [RelationName2],"")
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your data on separate lines, in the design view of the textbox enter this (for line breaks, press ctrl/enter **inside quote marks**):

```
=[Company Name] & "(ctrl/enter)
" & [Street Name and number] & "(ctrl/enter)
" & [Zipcode]
```